# How to sum numbers entered by the user using Python and display the total?

Tags: python

My task is:

Write a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters “done”. Once “done” is entered, print out the total, count, and average of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a number, detect their mistake using try and except and print an error message and skip to the next number.

My idea was to append the numbers entered by the user to a list and after that loop through the list to sum the number and calculate the average using this total divided by the length of the list. Does that work? However, my list does not append integers, only strings.  Besides, the word 'done' was also appended to the list.

my code is:

```
x=[ ]
while True:
    line = input('enter a number: ')
    x.append(line)
    if line == 'done':
        break
```

my desired output is:

```
Enter a number: 4

Enter a number: 5

Enter a number: bad data

Enter a number: 7

Enter a number: done

16 3 5.333333333333333
```

Comment: `raw_input()` reads strings as-is and returns strings, but `input()` expects Python's terms, like `1` for int, but `'done'` for string. Use `raw_input()`. for number use `int()` and catch exceptions of casting

Comment: @Paul-AG `raw_input()` only works for python2.

Comment: @Paul-AG Note that `raw_input` only exists in Python 2.  In Python 3 `input` returns a string as you would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My idea was to append the numbers entered by the user to a list and after that loop through the list to sum the number and calculate the average using this total divided by the length of the list. Does that work?

Yes, that sounds like the perfect solution.

> However, my list does not append integers, only strings.

Convert the input to an `int` before appending it:

```
x.append(int(line))
```

This will fail if `line` cannot be converted to an `int`, so you probably *actually* want:

```
try:
    x.append(int(line))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

> Besides, the word 'done' was also appended to the list.

Check for the string `'done'` *before* you append it.

```
if line == 'done':
    break
try:
    x.append(int(line))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Finally, you can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to do your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do, assuming the user can only input integers:

```
x=[]
while True:
    try:
        line = input('enter a number: ')
        if line == 'done':
            break
        x.append(int(line))
    except:
        pass
print(sum(x),len(x),sum(x)/len(x))
```

---

If the user should be able to input floats:

```
x=[]
while True:
    try:
        line = input('enter a number: ')
        if line == 'done':
            break
        x.append(float(line))
    except:
        pass
print(sum(x),len(x),sum(x)/len(x))
```

Comment: I know that I can't sum a list of strings. I asked those questions because I did not manage to convert the input into integers using int(). I understand my mistake now. Thanks anyway.